# Github invalid path error - unable to clone repository into GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, repository, git-clone, github-for-windows

I am new to GitHub and trying to clone my team's repository into my GitHub Desktop. However, I get the following error.

Cloning into 'C:\Users\prisc\github\sex-bias\sex.bias'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 809, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (29/29), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 809 (delta 8), reused 22 (delta 5), pack-reused 780
Receiving objects: 100% (809/809), 206.22 MiB | 30.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (340/340), done.
error: invalid path 'Icon?'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

Any ideas what is happening? I've also tried cloning from the terminal and get the same error.

Thanks,
Pri

Comment: There seems to be a file named `Icon?` in the repository which your system doesn't like.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Just renaming it to Icon didn't work though so I had to change the name completely and then name it back to Icon for it to register that there was no longer an invalid character.

Answer (score 1):

The cloning process succeeded, indicating that the issue is not related to Git credentials or network connectivity. However, the checkout process failed. What does this mean? It means that if you navigate to the folder of the cloned repository in the explorer, you won’t find any files written to the disk.
This error suggests that you have some error in the file name path or some trailing whitespace somewhere.

The reason why you get the error is that Windows doesn’t support trailing space characters and automatically removes them when saving a file. On the other hand, Linux does support both leading and trailing whitespaces in filenames.

Git knows about these limitations and has a special config setting to control it:

core.protectNTFS

If set to true, do not allow checkout of paths that would cause problems with the NTFS filesystem, e.g. conflict. with 8.3 “short” names. Defaults to true on Windows, and false elsewhere.

The reason why other people can clone the repo without issues is that core.protectNTFS is set to false (manually or because of underlying OS)

So, to clone the repo on Windows you can use the following command:

```
git clone -c core.protectNTFS=false <repo url>
```